# Custom in-desk panel

Tags: usb, ethernet, thunderbolt, usb-c

I would like to get rid of cable clutter and enhance my desk. However, I'm struggling to find the components for making it work. What I would like to do is including ports in the table, mainly Ethernet and USB ports.

Ethernet is the easy part, for instance I could just use some keystone frame such as [this](https://www.delock.de/produkte/G_86283/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en) (although I'd hope for something more efficient, space-wise, 4 on an 8cm diameter element seems a bit few) and put Ethernet keystone modules in it.

The USB part is the tricky one. I want different kinds of USB ports, the most important ones are:
Thunderbolt 3 ports (NOT USB-C 3.1 ports), supporting 40 Gbps if cable length is not too long (and 20 Gbps otherwise), with support for Apple's PD profiles up to 100W (18W, 87W, and 96W). I can't find any keystones doing this, not even USB-C above 60W. What I found is a [panel mount cable](https://www.agalink.com/40gbps-thunderbolt-3-male-to-female-ethernet-panel-mount-extension-cable.html), but this only seems to be available in wholesale (500+ units, I maybe need 5) from China, and I don't think it's ideal with the screws, I haven't found any frames to put into a table for which this would be suitable.

In addition, some USB-A Ports (3.0+, with ability to charge devices through them) and we're good. I doubt those will be an issue. Overall, if I'd manage 4 ports each (4 Ethernet, 4 TB3, 4 USB-A) I'd be fine.

Any ideas for any put-in-desk frames where I could include such ports, as efficient as possible? Also for the modules for the ports I mentioned, in particular the TB3 ports?
No restrictions on the system, if it's keystone that's good, if it's anything else that's fine, too.